# Modify value returned by Oracle regexp_replace backreference expression

Tags: regex, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have a string that contains values such as "String1...String2..." etc. I am trying to use the Oracle regexp_replace built-in to replace these with "StringA...StringB" and so on. I have done the regex pattern to find the strings and can reference the two parts of the pattern separately as demonstrated by the \1-----\2 in the replace string arguement:

```
with d as (select '<PatFactors><String1>0</String1><String2>0</String2><String3>0</String3><String4>0</String4><String5>0</String5><String6>0</String6><String7>0</String7><String8>0</String8><String9>0</String9><String10>0</String10><String11>0</String11><String12>0</String12><String13>0</String13><String14>0</String14><String15>0</String15><String16>0</String16><String17>0</String17><String18>0</String18><String19>0</String19><String20>0</String20><String21>0</String21><String22>0</String22><String23>0</String23><String24>0</String24><String25>0</String25><String26>0</String26><String27>0</String27><String28>0</String28><String29>0</String29><String30>0</String30></PatFactors>' as o_requestdata
             from dual)   
select regexp_replace(o_requestdata, '([Ss]tring)([0-9]+)', '\1-----\2'/*||chr(ascii('A')-1+to_number('\2'))*/ ) from d;
```

What I would like to do is keep the back reference \1 and then pass \2 into an expression like the one that is commented out. Unfortunately this gets an invalid number error if I uncomment this section.

Does anyone know if it is possible to perform operations on a back reference like this or can you think of any alternatives other than doing a straight replace 30 times for each value?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that to_number() knows nothing about backreferences. You need the backreference from the regular expression function in order to pass to to_number() but \2 has no meaning outside of the regular expression call, so it is the chicken before the egg, so to speak.

Comment: I figured that this would be the case, was just interested to see if anyone knew of a suitable workaround.

Comment: You should be able to workaround it, its just that the solution may be a bit unwieldy. You should be able to write a SQL statement that does full replacement of all patterns matching the regex with replacements. I just doubt it will be a 1-2 liner replacement for what you have.